# Javascript SVG error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a series of SVG maps that I am displaying with jquery.
When you go to the first page, the US Map shows on the left, and the initial state shows on the right, with county region attributes highlighted.
If you click any other state, and then go back to the original state, the attributes have disappeared.
HOW CAN I CHANGE THE CODE HERE TO MAKE THE ATTRIBUTES FOR EACH STATE WITH COUNTIES ON THE RIGHT SHOW AS THE USER CLICKS THROUGH THE STATES ON THE LEFT?
I do not want the attributes to disappear.
Here is the code and a screen capture of what is going on. On the third screen, I need the attributes to show like the first screen.

-----code-----

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('#mapsvg-usa').mapSvg({source: 'maps/usa.svg', width: 1200, responsive: 1,
            colors: {background: 'transparent', hover: 4, selected: 10, stroke: '#ffffff'},
            tooltipsMode: 'names',
            regions: {'CO': {selected: true}},
            onClick: function(){

               var file = 'usa-'+this.name.toLowerCase()+'.svg';

               console.log($('#mapsvg-states').html());

               if($('#mapsvg-states').find('svg').length){
                $('#mapsvg-states').mapSvg().destroy();
               }

               $('#mapsvg-states').mapSvg({
                    source : 'maps/counties/'+file,
                    //responsive: 1,
                    colors: {background: 'transparent', base: "#DDDDDD", stroke: '#ffffff'},
                    width: $('#mapsvg-usa').width(),
                    height: $('#mapsvg-usa').height(),
                    tooltipsMode: 'combined',
                    zoomButtons: {show: true, location: 'right'},
                    zoom: 1,
                    pan: 1
               });

            }
            });

           $('#mapsvg-states').mapSvg({
                source : 'maps/counties/usa-co.svg',
                responsive: 1,
                colors: {background: 'transparent', stroke: '#ffffff'},
                width: $('#mapsvg-usa').width(),
                tooltipsMode: 'names',
                zoomButtons: {show: true, location: 'right'},
                zoom: 1,
                pan: 1,
                regions: {
                    Douglas: {tooltip: 'RFC Submitted', attr: {fill: '#fc0'}},
                    Jefferson: {tooltip: 'RFC Submitted', attr: {fill: '#fc0'}}}
           });


        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#maplinks a').on('click', function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var file = $(this).attr('data-svg');


               if($('#mapsvg-other').find('svg').length){
                $('#mapsvg-other').empty().mapSvg().destroy();
               }

               $('#mapsvg-other').mapSvg({
                    source : 'maps/'+file,
                    responsive: 1,
                    width: $('#mapsvg-other-cont').width(),
                    height: $('#mapsvg-other-cont').height(),
                    tooltipsMode: 'names',
                    zoomButtons: {show: true, location: 'left'},
                    zoom: 1,
                    pan: 1
               });

            });

        </script>
```

[image: Here are the 3 screen captures show how the attributes disappear]

Answer (score 0):

The map that is being loaded when clicking on a state doesn't have the regions data included like the initially loaded map.
copy the regions code into it

```
regions: {
             Douglas: {tooltip: 'RFC Submitted', attr: {fill: '#fc0'}},
             Jefferson: {tooltip: 'RFC Submitted', attr: {fill: '#fc0'}}
}
```

Hope that helps.